# Google Sheets - Problem with ARRAYFORMULA and COUNTIFS Combined

Tags: google-sheets

My **Sheet1** is being filled automatically by an **IFTTT recipe** collecting articles matching a subject list of 5 countries, populating a table like this:

```
Sheet1
        A            B            C
1| Date⁤⁤ ⁤⁤ ⁤⁤ ⁤⁤ ⁤⁤ ⁤⁤⁤⁤ ⁤⁤ |⁤⁤ Country⁤⁤ ⁤⁤ ⁤⁤⁤⁤ ⁤⁤⁤⁤ ⁤⁤ |⁤⁤ Title
2| 2017-12-01 |⁤⁤ Iran⁤⁤ ⁤⁤ ⁤⁤ ⁤⁤ ⁤⁤ ⁤⁤⁤⁤ ⁤⁤  |⁤⁤ bla bla bla
3| 2017-12-01 |⁤⁤ North Korea |⁤⁤ bla bla bla
4| 2017-12-02 |⁤⁤ Iran⁤⁤ ⁤⁤ ⁤⁤ ⁤⁤ ⁤⁤ ⁤⁤ ⁤⁤ ⁤⁤ |⁤⁤ bla bla bla
5| 2017-12-02 |⁤⁤ Yemen⁤⁤ ⁤⁤ ⁤⁤ ⁤⁤ ⁤⁤⁤⁤  ⁤⁤⁤⁤ |⁤⁤ bla bla bla
6| 2017-12-03 |⁤⁤ Iran⁤⁤ ⁤⁤ ⁤⁤ ⁤⁤ ⁤⁤ ⁤⁤⁤⁤ ⁤⁤ ⁤⁤ |⁤⁤ bla bla bla
7| 2017-12-03 |⁤⁤ Iran⁤⁤ ⁤⁤ ⁤⁤ ⁤⁤ ⁤⁤ ⁤⁤ ⁤⁤ ⁤⁤ |⁤⁤ bla bla bla
```

In **Sheet2** I would like to have a table that counts how many articles are written about each country, each day, like this:

```
Sheet2
       A             B            C         D
1| Date       | Iran       | North Korea| Yemen
2| 2017-12-01 | 1          | 1          | 0
3| 2017-12-02 | 1          | 0          | 1
4| 2017-12-03 | 2          | 0          | 0
```

To do so, i've placed in **Sheet2!A2** the following formula:

```
=UNIQUE(Sheet1!A2:A)
```

That gives in **Sheet2 Column A** a list of all unique date values fed in by the IFTTT recipe into Sheet1.

My challenge is how to count the number of country appearances in **Sheet1!B2:B** for each unique date.

I tried using the **COUNTIFS** formula inside an **ARRAYFORMULA** to automatically populate lines as **Sheet1** progresses, like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A), "", COUNTIFS(Sheet1!B2:C,"="&"Iran",Sheet1!A2:A, "="&A2:A)))
```

However the formula always return the value of 1 for all unique dates.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you @ale, figured out that my first question did not provide enough details so i deleted it and drafted another one...

Comment: You should have, instead, edited the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a pivot table.

Select the original data, choose `Data` > `Pivot Table`.

From the Pivot Table Editor, add as ROW the column  "Date", as COLUMN the "Country", and as VALUE the "Title"

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you @joel-spolsky, pivot table manages to do the job, however, it seems like pivot tables are more difficult to work with using graphs... the 'Grand Total' line and column + impossible to sort Z-A. Any known solution for that?